# How to provide File and some para. to POST API using Python/ C#?

Tags: c#, test-automation-framework, rest-api, api, api-automation

Team,
I am trying to provide File and some para. as a input for API. Expecting output based on validation.

Even after providing both inputs correctly, I am getting File as **null** with **length 0**. Below are the details of my env:

- Windows 11
- API Automation
- POST method

How to provide File and some para. to POST API?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Perhaps show us the request/response.

Comment: Actually found many solutions for sending file to POST but with file I want to send some para. too. I have created File obj and I am able to see file fetch successfully as length is > 0 but its become null when it calls server functions

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this

```
   public void POST_GetClientList()
        {
            string url = "https://XXXXX.XXX.XXX/GetClientList";
            string OutPutdata = null;
            byte status = 0;
            string ResponsCode = null;


            var client = new HttpClient();
            var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "cja@xxx.com")
                };

            try
            {
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
                var response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
                ResponsCode = response.ToString().Substring(12, 3);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }


            Assert.IsTrue(ResponsCode.Contains("200"));

        }
```

Comment: yes tried.. But what about file and some para.? Where/How should I give?

Comment: new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "cja@xxx.com") these are the parameters, You have to give it like KeyValuePair

Comment: May be I understood the question in wrong way.

Comment: No - What you are saying is correct I have implemented in somewhat same way but just can't proceed as I have to send File and two more parameter simultaneously. If I did so - File obj is getting null :( Finding the solutions. Hope if you have solution for this